# "boxrule=0pt" doesn't do well without "enhanced jigsaw" in tcolorbox

Tags: tcolorbox

I was LaTeXing about "leaving a large blank" when I want to hide the answer but want some blank for the students to write, one guy told me to use tcolorbox's "invisible" to have a try.

And I've tried for a while, and it did work, but something went wrong when I use "enhanced jigsaw".

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-3]
test

test
\begin{tcolorbox}[invisible,
  % enhanced jigsaw,
  breakable,
  colback=white,boxrule=0mm
  ]
\begin{enumerate}
  \item 1
  \item 2
  \item 3
  \item 4
  \item 5
  \item 6
  \item 7
  \item 8
  \item 9
  \item 10
\end{enumerate}
\end{tcolorbox}
test
\end{document}
```

[image]

you can see there is still a tiny line around the box, while there isn't if I use the "enhanced jigsaw".

I wonder what's wrong with it, and if I don't use enhanced jigsaw, are there some ways to make the line invisible?

Comment: you normally need some enhanced skin here, e.g. enhanced, frame hidden, interior hidden,  would work too.

Comment: Thanks for offering another method, I add "enhanced, frame hidden" and remove the "boxrule=0mm", and it works.

Comment: This is most likely a PDF viewer issue/feature. In normal "skin", the frame is not drawn as a rounded rectangle, but the difference of several rounded filled rectangles (first frame rectangle, then interior and title rectangles on top of it), see the package manual, sec. 9.4 "Drawing Scheme". So when you set `boxrule=0pt` and leave title empty, the frame and interior rectangles will have the same size. Then some PDF viewer will render gray frames to indicate users that there's some graph just overlaid.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now my question have been fully resolved.